# Browsing network drive crashes File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

When browsing to specific folders in a network drive File Explorer crashes. However, when accessing it directly by accessing the network path in FIle Explorer it works without any issue.

The issue that occurs is that the folder is accessed, and after that the explorer process crashes closing everything that relies on this process.

A temporary fix that we have setup at the moment is to add a network location instead of a network drive as that seems to work.

Any idea what might be causing this? Event Logs aren't giving any clues either.

Answer (score 0):

Enabled "Always show icons, never thumbnails" in Folder Options, worked after that when accessing from Network Drive. Odd thing is that it only happened when accessing the path from a Network Drive and not if it was a Network Folder.